# How to validate propery exists in Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I'm trying to validate if a property exists in a Properties object, if doesn't exist I need to request it and add the property. Currently I'm stuck at validating if the properity exists.

```
Properties props; //Where props is entered as an argument

        if(props.getProperty("oauth.consumerKey") == null){
            //If propertie doesn't exist do something
        }
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: what is your question ? what error you are getting ? what property do you have in your properties file ?

Comment: "*...if doesn't exist I need to request it and add the property.*"  --  Request it from who? some other property source? the user?  Add it to what? `props`? the property files itself?

Comment: Yes, I want to add it into props. I want to add it for example, let's say the property should have "oauth.consumerKey" that has a value of whatever the key is -> props("oauth.consumerKey", "value"). I want to know if either "oauth.consumerKey" or the value exists in properties. Thank you for your time guys!

Answer (score 1):

There are not so many things which you can do:

1. You can throw an Exception.
2. You can set the value by default.
3. You can request a user to add the property with the message "You can't go to the next step, until the moment when property will not be specified".